# Add a clickable overlay image to an 360 virtual tour

Tags: java, html, css, iframe

I wanted to add an overlay image to a 360 virtual tour, so when the user clicks on the image it fades out and you can play with the 360. See the image below of how I want.

Thanks in advance!
José

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O7BT.jpg)

I tried using video code but it didn't work well.

Comment: Hi, could you show us the code you have so far and include a bit more description of what is required and what isn't working. I am not clear whether you have an existing virtual tour and just want to put a (fadeable) image over it or whether there is more required. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with putting code into your question.

Comment: Hi A Haworth, I added the code below. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please put your code into your question (use the <> icon when editing) rather than in an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
<div id="vidFrame" class="play">
<iframe id="vimeo-video" src="https://downloads.robertgranoff.com/Tishman_Realty/110_East_16th_St_360_Tour.html" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
<img id="vimeo-id" width="100%" height="400" src="https://i.ibb.co/XbLH2G7/overlay-rg.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#vimeo-id,iframe{
position:absolute;
}
#vimeo-id{
cursor:pointer; 
}

.overlay {
position: absolute;
width: 40%;
left: 30%;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).